# Differences between these 2 patch antenna arrays?

Tags: patch-antenna

BLE5.2 based AOA applications are very popular. There're some devkits for this purpose on the market.

One of them is https://www.insightsip.com/products/bluetooth-smart-modules/isp1907

The other one is https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/xplr-aoa-1-kit#tab-documentation-resources

If we look at antennas on the boards, the antenna from ISIP has 12 patches that are connected from a **single point** to RF switches.  The antenna from Ublox has 5 patches that are connected from **dual points** to RF switches.

What is the difference between these 2 antenna designs in terms of advantages/disadvantages?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If these are really just switches, then, seeing that these patches are symmetrical relative to the diagonal (i.e, square), they just switch polarizations.

So, if you want to play with different polarizations, this helps. If not, not. Having the option to pick polarizations however, definitely, gives you a diversity gain ("Selection Combining").

Comment: Yeah, they're PE42442  SP4T switches. Both arrays for AOA detection. What about the first one's polarization?  What do they intend to switch H and V planes in the second design? For selectivity or do they want the same result with less antenna? Thank you.

Comment: Polarization of first one: look up "patch antenna polarization"; What do they intend by switching polarization: I'm not Ublox, I can't tell you, but I gave a possible reason. Same result with less antenna: well, depends on how much the polarization paths are correlated, and how much different antennas would be correlated.